# What is the Islamic word for hell & heaven?

Tags: quran, eschatology

I understand that *Dunya* means this world, and that *Akhira* mean the hereafter. Now, can *Akhira* refer to heaven or hell? Or does it mean the life after death?

What are the Islamic words for Hell and Heaven, especially as referenced in the Quran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a site which you can use to learn about the conceptual relations between the words in Quran: [Ontology of Quranic Concepts](http://corpus.quran.com/ontology.jsp).

If you go to the entry for [afterlife locations](http://corpus.quran.com/concept.jsp?id=afterlife-location) it list two main places: Paradise (الجنة), Hell (جهنم)
and if you go to their entries you can find other related words:

- [Paradise (الجنة)](http://corpus.quran.com/concept.jsp?id=paradise)

  - Firdous (الفردوس)
  - Garden of Eden (جنات عدن)
  - Lote Tree (السدرة)
  - Salsabil (سلسبيل)
- [Hell (جهنم)](http://corpus.quran.com/concept.jsp?id=hell)

  - Saqar (سقر)
  - Sijjeen (سجين)
  - Zaqqum (زقوم)
  - Ladha (لظى)

You can find the verses that used them by going to their entries: [verses related to paradise](http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=con%3Aparadise), [verses related to hell](http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=con%3Ahell).

PS: [Ontology of Quranic Concepts](http://corpus.quran.com/ontology.jsp) doesn't seem to be complete and there are some words which are not in the graph in general but it is a good source to check.

Comment: +1: I should have acdepted this long ago.

Answer (score 2):

general names are below
heaven,Paradise:**Janna**(جَنَّة)(pl. جَنّات jannat)
link:[[2:82]](http://quran.com/2/82)
hell:**Jahannam**(جَهَنَّم)link:[[3:12]](http://quran.com/3/12)  
other names
heaven:جَنَّاتُ عَدْنٍ(reference[16:31]), دَارُ السَّلَامِ(reference[6:127])etc.
hell:النَّارِ(means fire)(reference[2:39]), الْجَحِيمِ(reference[5:10]), سَقَرَ(reference[54:48]or[74:42])etc.